# In Gecode, accessing home/space variables values from merit function

Tags: gecode

In **Gecode**, I am using a **merit function** to select variables when branching.

In order to compute variable v's merit, I need to access **some other variables values**, but it looks like at the time the merit function is called, the space variables have not yet been asigned any values :

```
Exception: IntVar::val: Attempt to access value of unassigned variable.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to access variables values in merit functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that while you are still searching a variable won't just have 1 value, its domain is still larger than 1. This means that there might still be different values that a variable can take. Until there is only one value left in its domain you are not allowed to use the `val` method.

There are different solutions for this problem depending on how you want to use the value domain:

- The best way to test a variable against a single value is using the `in` method. This method returns `true` if the value is in the domain of the variable.
- To check variables against each other you would generally use the `min` and `max` methods to compare their domains.
- If the value is only relevant when it is assigned, then you would check that the cardinality (size of the domain) is 1, using the `size` method, before using the `val` method.

These are the most general cases, but there are countless ways to interact with variables. Be sure to check the [IntVar documentation](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/classGecode_1_1IntVar.html), where these and all other methods for the `IntVar` class are described.

Comment: Solved by using `min()`, which was the correct way to go in my case.

Comment: Solved by using `size()` on an `IntVarArgs` element that represented the index to an array of known words for a crosswords. Thanks !! The doc is hard to decypher for one's particular case.